# SMO Restore Events Never Fire

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application, smo

We have this scripted restore process , i am trying to add some logging for the percent completed so we have an idea of how far some of our long running backups are into the process

I added an event handler to the PercentCompleted event in our Restore handler but it seems that it never fires as we do not receive any output at all from the callback

Anyone have an idea why this is not working

```
    public void Restore(string backupPath)
    {
        Logger.Log("Restoring database {0} from backup {1}", Name, backupPath);

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(Server.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            var smoConn = new ServerConnection(con);
            smoConn.StatementTimeout = 1200; // FMNET-20792. 20 minutes (default was 10 minutes)
            var server = new Server(smoConn);

            Logger.Log("Killing all processes in {0}", Name);
            try
            {
                server.KillAllProcesses(Name);
            }
            catch (FailedOperationException e)
            {
                Logger.Log("Killing all processed failed with error below. Will still attemp to restore the DB");
                Logger.Log(e.ToString());
            }

            var restore = new Restore();

            restore.PercentComplete += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Logger.Log("Percent Complete {0,3}%", args.Percent);
            };
            restore.Devices.AddDevice(backupPath, DeviceType.File);
            restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            restore.Database = Name;
            restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;

            string serverDataPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(server.DefaultFile)
                                        ? server.Information.MasterDBPath
                                        : server.DefaultFile;
            serverDataPath = Path.GetFullPath(serverDataPath);
            Logger.Verbose("Server default data path: {0}", serverDataPath);

            string serverLogPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(server.DefaultLog)
                                       ? server.Information.MasterDBLogPath
                                       : server.DefaultLog;
            serverLogPath = Path.GetFullPath(serverLogPath);
            Logger.Verbose("Server default log path: {0}", serverLogPath);

            var files = restore.ReadFileList(server);
            int dataFileIndex = 0;
            int logFileIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in files.Rows)
            {
                string logicalName = row["LogicalName"].ToString();
                string type = row["Type"].ToString();

                string newPhysicalPath;
                if (type == "D")
                {
                    newPhysicalPath = string.Format("{0}_Data{1}.mdf", Name,
                                                 dataFileIndex > 0 ? dataFileIndex.ToString() : string.Empty);
                    newPhysicalPath = Path.Combine(serverDataPath, newPhysicalPath);
                    dataFileIndex++;
                }
                else if (type == "L")
                {
                    newPhysicalPath = string.Format("{0}_Log{1}.ldf", Name,
                                                     logFileIndex > 0 ? dataFileIndex.ToString() : string.Empty);
                    newPhysicalPath = Path.Combine(serverLogPath, newPhysicalPath);
                    logFileIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Unsupported file type: " + type);
                }

                var relocateFile = new RelocateFile(logicalName, newPhysicalPath);
                Logger.Log("Will relocate {0} to {1}", logicalName, newPhysicalPath);
                restore.RelocateFiles.Add(relocateFile);
            }

            restore.SqlRestore(server);
            Logger.Log("Restore complete. Renaming logical files");
            var db = server.Databases[Name];
            foreach (FileGroup fg in db.FileGroups)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fg.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    string oldName = fg.Files[i].Name;
                    string newName = string.Format("{0}_Data{1}", Name, i > 0 ? i.ToString() : string.Empty);
                    if (!oldName.Equals(newName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        Logger.Log("Renaming {0} to {1}", oldName, newName);
                        fg.Files[i].Rename(newName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Logger.Log("Oldname equals newname ({0}), nothing to do", oldName);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < db.LogFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                string oldName = db.LogFiles[i].Name;
                string newName = string.Format("{0}_Log{1}", Name, i > 0 ? i.ToString() : string.Empty);
                if (!oldName.Equals(newName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Logger.Log("Renaming {0} to {1}", oldName, newName);
                    db.LogFiles[i].Rename(newName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Log("Oldname equals newname ({0}), nothing to do", oldName);
                }
            }

            // Ensure FMAccess user exists in DB and is properly mapped
            var fmAccessUser = Env.GetUser("FMAccess");
            if (fmAccessUser == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Credentials with id=\"FMAccess\" don't exist in the specified environment file. FMAccess user is required when restoring a database.");
            }

            Logger.Log("Ensuring user {0} exists in the database {1}.", fmAccessUser.Login, Name);

            // If a user already exists in DB we drop and re-create it because after restore the mapping to an existing SQL login will be lost anyway.
            if (db.Users.Contains(fmAccessUser.Login))
            {
                Logger.Verbose("User already exists in DB, dropping.");
                db.Users[fmAccessUser.Login].Drop();
            }

            Logger.Verbose("Creating user {0}", fmAccessUser.Login);
            var u = new User(db, fmAccessUser.Login) { DefaultSchema = "dbo", Login = fmAccessUser.Login };
            u.Create();
            var dboRole = db.Roles["db_owner"];
            dboRole.AddMember(fmAccessUser.Login);
            Logger.Verbose("User created successfully");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you set `restore.PercentCompleteNotification = 1;`?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you add the event handler just before you call `restore.SqlRestore(server);`?